# Jquery select2 plugin allowClear behavior

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2-4

I'm trying to use the new version of select2 Plugin (4.0.2.rc1) but I have a problem with allowClear action.

```
$('select').select2({
   theme: 'bootstrap',
   placeholder: '..',
   allowClear: true
});
```

With the version 3.5.2 the "clear" action works well, but with this version when I click to x to clean the choice will clean the choice but even open the drop-down menu

[image]

How can I fix this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested this is the solution to the problem, hoping it will correct the problem in the new version of the plugin.

```
$('select').select2({
   theme: 'bootstrap',
   placeholder: '..',
   allowClear: true
});

/* FIX */
var $el = $('select');
$el.on('select2:unselecting', function(e) {
   $el.data('unselecting', true);
}).on('select2:open', function(e) { // note the open event is important
   if ($el.data('unselecting')) {
       $el.removeData('unselecting'); // you need to unset this before close
            $el.select2('close');
   }
});
```